# Best practice for abstracting Angular HTML code?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend, angular-ngmodel

In my Angular project I have a basic component

**TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cardboxes',
  templateUrl: './cardboxes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cardboxes.component.scss']
})
export class CardboxesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

In the HTML file, I use this component about 16 times. I have it completely hardcoded for 16 different "cardboxes", like so:

**HTML**

```
                    <mat-card id="CARDBOX">
                        <img class="logoy" src="assets/image" height=35px>
                        <a href="link1.com" class="button">Box1</a>
                        <input type="image" id="info" title="Click for description" src="assets/image2" height=20px/>
                    </mat-card> 
                    
                    <mat-card id="CARDBOX">
                        <img class="logoy" src="assets/image3" height=35px/>
                        <a href="link2.com" class="button">Box2</a>
                        <input type="image" id="info" title="Click for description" src="assets/image2.png" height=20px/>
                    </mat-card>
```

Essentially this renders a little box with a couple images, and a button that takes the user to an external link. There are 16 of these boxes typed into the HTML file, and everytime I want to add a new one, I have to rewrite essentially the same code with only the inputs different.

As you can see this format is heavily reused, but it is arduously hardcoded into the HTML file. Is there a way that I could abstract the reused code so that it is not tediously hardcoded in? How can I make a template for this that can be used multiple times? Going further, how can I add to, remove from, and alter this list of items?

Comment: It's also bad because IDs must be unique to the document.

Comment: @HereticMonkey What is bad?

Comment: The code presented here. There are two elements with the id "info", for instance.

Comment: @HereticMonkey what exactly is bad about it? Is there a problem I should look into?

Comment: It's invalid HTML. Also, the function `getElementById` will only return the first element with the specified id.

Comment: @HereticMonkey what do you suggest I do instead? Or how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

In your component.ts file, you can add a property called something like: `cards`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cardboxes',
  templateUrl: './cardboxes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cardboxes.component.scss']
})
export class CardboxesComponent implements OnInit {
  cards = [
       {
          'imageUrl': '/assets/image.png',
          'link': 'link1.com',
          ... More Stuff YOu like
       },
       {
          'imageUrl': '/assets/image1.png',
          'link': 'link1.com',
          ... More Stuff YOu like
       },
       .. More items ...
  ];
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Then in your html, you can loop through that `cards` array:

```
<mat-card id="CARDBOX" *ngFor="let card of cards">
    <img class="logoy" src="{{ card.imageUrl }}" height=35px/>
    <a href="{{ card.link }}" class="button">Box2</a>
    <input type="image" id="info" title="Click for description" src="assets/image2.png" height=20px/>
</mat-card>
```

Note: I would also avoid adding the `CARDBOX` id to each element, as that is bad practice in HTML5.

Then your problem should be solved ... Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: Do you suggest I do this within the existing class, or make a new interface/class?

Comment: Either could work, but I would suggest making an interface/class, although, for simplicity in my answer, I decided to use the existing class.

Comment: If I only wanted to display a certain amount of the list, say, only the first 4 items, and then display the next 4 items someplace else, would that be possible with ngFor?

Comment: @bensalerno Yes, in the `*ngFor` you could use `let card of cards.slice(start, end)`. This will use get part of the array, depending on the options you send. Documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 2):

Did not test it, but a ngFor can work wonders in this cases.
Make an array of a new interface cardDetails

```
export interface CardDetail {
   id: number;
   image: string;
   link: string;
   button: string;
   input: string;
}

<mat-card *ngFor="let item of cardDetailArray">
    <img class="logoy" src="{{item.image}}" height=35px>
    <a href="{{item.link}}" class="button">{{item.button}}</a>
    <input type="image" id="info" title="Click for description" src="{{image.input}}" height=20px/>
</mat-card>
```

If it's literally only a diff on numbers. just make a number array[1,2,3,...x] and use the ngfor let item in numberArray , concatenate all things with the number variable.

Comment: In this case, where would I define my cards? Like where do I fill out id, image, link, etc for the ones that already exist?